# How to run Grails in Command Prompt with jenkins

Tags: batch-file, grails, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

i have a project which is made with grails 2.4.3 version and it needed to be run in command prompt.
I have made a batch file to run all the commands, 
now i have to make a build through Jenkins, but when in run that .bat file in Jenkins it gives error:

`Error |
Error occurred running Grails CLI: null`

but when i run the bat file by double click it runs absolutely fine.

batch file:

> call grails clean || exit /b
>
> call grails compile || exit /b
>
> call grails package || exit /b
>
> call grails war || exit /b

Comment: I would rather use `gradle` here, for all these tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grails 2.4.x is not shipped with Gradle. I would use the grails wrapper (`grailsw`).

Take a look on the [official docs](http://docs.grails.org/2.4.x/guide/single.html#wrapper) to see more details about the wrapper but essentially you can execute your commands as follows:

```
./grailsw clean 

./grailsw compile 

./grailsw package

./grailsw war
```